# How to remove Windows List form Ubuntu-MATE Top Panel

Tags: 14.04, indicator, panel, mate

I managed to delete my top panel on an Ubuntu-MATE (14.04) desktop. Then I restored it, but by mistake I also added the Windows List indicator.

How can I remove it? It's already in the bottom panel already and I don't want another one.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out I only needed to find the right spot where to right-click. Then a menu opened and I was able to remove the indicator.

[image: click here to move Window List]

Now I'd like to know how to add the Recent Files applet to the panel tho.

Comment: I added screenshot with *right spot*.

Comment: My bad, I was using a background color for the panel that made it very difficult to see the three dots...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what icons you have surrounding the Window List icon on the panel, you may find you are unable to find the right spot to get the "remove from panel" context menu to appear.

I had a folder launcher icon to the left of the Window List icon, and no matter how much I tried, no way could I get it to show the right context menu to remove from panel. Then I hit on this idea and sure enough, after removing one or more of the surrounding icons, the state of the Window List icon became such that I could get the menu to appear and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

To make it easier to find where to click the panel, so that it will display the necessary context menu for removing an item from the panel, first go to the panel properties and boost the size to a large number.

This not only increases the panel height, but also makes the panel contents scale up in size accordingly. This makes it far easier to make small changes to exactly where you are clicking, so that you can find the right spot more easily.

[image]